# Measurability of random function with values in $C(K,E)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ be compact, and let $E$ be a separable Banach space. Further, let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ a probability space. I would like to show that a certain a random function
$$
f \colon \Omega\to C(K,E)
$$
is measurable, where $C(K,E)$ is the space of continuous functions on $K$ to $E$, with the supremum norm. This means I have to show $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(C(K,E))$, but I do not know where to start, as I do not know exactly how Borel sets $B$ in $\mathcal{B}(C(K,E))$. Can anyone help me getting started?

Thanks

Comment: what is C(K,E)? Do you mean continuous functions from K to E?

Comment: @ThomasKojar thanks, I have now changed the question so as to explain that $C(K,E)$ is the space of continuous functions on $K$ to $E$, with standard norm.

Comment: In terms of measurability, we need to know the particular $f$. In terms of Borel sets in $C(K,E)$, this is a function space and so you need to equip it with some norm eg. supremum norm; then they will have the sup-norm topology. Whereas if you equipped it with L2 norm, the Borel sets will be different.

Comment: Also, this is a research question, really: the function $f$ I am considering comes from the solution to a Banach-valued dynamical system, and I am trying to understand how to prove measurability for the particular $f$ that I am after

Comment: eg. see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148349/open-and-closed-balls-in-ca-b?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for helping. Let us say: $E = C([-1,1]$, with the sup norm $\| \cdot \|_\infty$, $K = [0,T] \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $C(K,E)$ has now norm $\| u \| = \sup_{t \in [0,T]} \| u(t) \|_\infty$. And I am now considering $f \colon \Omega \to C(K,E)$, or $f \colon \Omega \to C([0,T],C([-1,1]))$ to spell it out

Answer (score 4):

The Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the space $C(K,E)$ of continuous functions from a compact metrizable space $K$ to a separable metric space with the induced uniform metric is generated by the evaluation maps of the form $f\mapsto f(x)$. See, for example, Lemma 4.53 in [Aliprantis & Border (2006)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-29587-9).

Therefore, your random function is measurable if for every $x\in K$, the value at $x$ is a random variable.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful

Comment: @GerardoMastracchio : Just in case, here are some relevant guidelines: https://mathoverflow.net/help/accepted-answer and https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers